# Expanding maps in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I made a locator map as well as 4 copies of said map for my friends now I want to expand the map but I need to know if I expand a locator map does the copies of the map I made prior to the expansion also update or will my friends need to expand theirs manually?

Answer (score 3):

**You will have to manually expand all of your friend's maps.** If you want, you could also make a fully expanded map, and then make multiple copies of the fully expanded map.